# Is it safe to travel in Greece during the riots about government spending cuts?

Tags: safety, greece, athens, event-based-effects

I am travelling to Athens, Greece, shortly, and have seen [reports of recent unrest](http://www.independent.ie/business/irish/greek-crisis-puts-euro17bn-irish-life-float-in-jeopardy-2800068.html). Should I be worried? Should I cancel my trip?

**Update**

It's fine, taxis are currently on strike, but Syntagma Sqaure is fine:

[image]

Comment: Where in Greece are you heading?  Some areas are worse then others in regards to rioting.

Comment: Where are you going in Greece, and how are you getting about? Strikes may be more of an issue that riots, depends on where you're off to and how!

Comment: @trip0d Athens...

Comment: I have this question as well.  [Rail service has been suspended](http://www.raileurope.ca/rail-tickets-passes/balkan-flexipass/discounts-and-pricing.html), apparently.  (So secondary question: Is it even feasible to stop in Greece while travelling through Europe?)

Comment: Another thing you should consider is if you have travel insurance or not (it may not cover civil unrest - check your policy) and/or return policies on some of the events you have already scheduled.  I would hate to waste large amounts of money.

Comment: Some friends of mine were in Athens last week, just for a day before flying home. They are still there as their passports were stolen from their parked car while visiting the Acropolis. Just a word of warning.

Comment: Given the current issues in Greece if you do go, try and swap all your Greek Euro notes for notes from other Euro countries as often as possible. If Greece collapses those notes will be worthless.

Comment: @Stuart That's absurd. The idea that Greek Euro notes could suddenly become worth nothing is completely wrong.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I suggest you don't cancel your trip.

I have been working in Athens during a period of unrest.

I can't predict what will happen, but usually many people demonstrate peacefully, then a small group of a hundred people starts facing the police for an hour, then a few people start throwing rocks/tear gas, and run a bit. Actual violence is very local, like one kilometer of a given avenue, during an hour. (I know this because I was inside the rock-throwing group taking pictures).

It is a very localized risk, so just stay away and you should be fine. Athens' traffic is probably a bigger danger, statistically.

My advice if you are worried would be: If you ever happen to see or hear unrest, just walk the other way and take a taxi to your hotel.

Of course, be prepared to delayed trains/buses/ferries due to strikes.

Comment: I think that strikes are by far the biggest annoyance you will have to face.

Comment: is it wiser to rent a car than take taxis in order to get around?

Answer (score 10):

We were in Athens last week. The local sentiment was that of peaceful resentment. We were instructed to stray away from any sort of congregation. Though, we did hear that tourist areas are immune to this (we are after all bringing in much-needed foreign funds)...

Answer (score 6):

The problem in Greece is not the "riots", it is more like everywhere where poverty is rising the risk of getting your things stolen. In hotels this is not a risk usually, but don't go out at 3 in the morning, expecting safety there. You are alone with the Pakistanis, Afgans, heroin addicts (and we've got a lot of them too...).

In the daytime Athens is safe. As for violence, it is directed towards police, and from police directed towards everyone who happens to be around. So don't be around demonstrations, unless you want to take photos for your news agency ... :)

Comment: Are you stereotyping particular immigrant groups as dangerous ?